# Vyatta: how do I view up fixed DHCP leases settings?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, vyatta

I'd like to know how could I get the MAC-IP DHCP associations.

I know that there is `show dhcp leases` but it only shows information about the active leases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the static mapping. This is part of your configuration, not part of a dynamically generated files. You can get it with :

```
show service dhcp-server
```

You can also see additional informations in

```
ls /var/lib/dhcp3/*
```

Comment: Actually I want that the association is not static but made the first time the clients requests an IP address.

Comment: And how is that different from the active leases? Those are client requests for an IP addresses which has been attributed...

Comment: The difference is that if I have a client that is not currently connected it does not appear in the active leases.
But, apparently, the MAC-IP binding is stored somewhere as it connects he gets the IP address it previously had.

Comment: I added the dhcp3 persitent lease folder.